# Alternative of STUFF function of SQL Server in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to know, there is any alternative for `STUFF()` (of SQL Server) in SQLite database?

Answer (score 2):

IMO, There is not any direct alternative function of `STUFF()` function of SQL Server in SQLite, I suggest you to use this:

When you have this in SQL Server:

```
STUFF(expression, start, numChars, newExpression)
```

Change it to below code in SQLite:

```
 Substr(expression, 1, start - 1) || newExpression || Substr(expression, start + numChars)
```

[[SQL Fiddle Demo example]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9eecb7/591)